# Hibernate not using Id to find entity

Tags: java, hibernate

Hibernate appears to not be using the Id field for one specific class.
My setup looks like this:

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class IdentifiableObject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A extends IdentifiableObject {

    private String field;
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = B.class)
    private B b;
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B extends IdentifiableObject {

    private TypeSomethingElse field;
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = C.class)
    private C c;
    @OneToMany(
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL
    )
    private List<A> as;
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "C")
public class C extends IdentifiableObject {

    @OneToMany(
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL
    )
    private List<B> bs;
}
```

In my code I save an object C to the database, use the data in the database to perform some calculations, create a jasper report and delete the object C from the database again. When deleting the C object I was getting this error:

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: A(field="something")

This Exception is thrown in the class:

```
public abstract AbstractEntityLoader {
    protected Object load(
        SharedSessionContractImplementor session,
        Object id,
        Object optionalObject,
        Serializable optionalId,
        LockOptions lockOptions){
        // Some code
    }
}
```

When the load method is triggered for the B objects, the id passed to the load method is the value of the field id. Whenever it is triggered for the A object it passes a A object with only the field attribute filled in, Our id is null. I personally would asume the method would use the Id field in both cases but it does not. Anyone knows what's happening here?

### JPA-Repositories:

I use auto implemented interfaces for deleting.

```
public interface CRepository extends IdentifiableObjectRepository<C>, JpaRepository<C, Integer> {

    C findById(Integer cId);
}
```

> **PS:** The @Data anotation is part of Lombok to provide getters and setters and some other useful methods.
>
> **PPS:** I have been able to get it to work by adding a new delete method to the JpaRepository: 'void deleteById(Integer id)', so it seems there is an issue with the default CRUDRepository delete method. This feels like a work around and I would still like to know what the reason is for this issue.

Comment: What is your code to fetch/delete the entity?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I've eddited the post to include that information.